# A strange construction of locks

Tags: visual, real, keys-and-locks, locks

This gate is locked with 6 locks. What is the purpose of this construction?

[image]

Comment: Is there any copyright on the image? I'd quite like to use it the next time that I am explaining [this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_encryption).

Comment: Interesting discussion around this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/EngineeringPorn/comments/11xrf27/or_gate)

Comment: Not sure about copyright. I found it on my Facebook feed, but don't know the original source.

Comment: If you arrive to find an unlocked state, you can tell which key was used to unlock it, which may give useful info on who is inside. This might be especially useful if the space accommodates very few people - perhaps even only one person, so you could tell if the occupant(s) are cleaning staff, maintenence staff, emergency services, workers, etc

Comment: I've seen this (or similar) picture quite a few times on various software security blogs I believe it's fairly old and well known...

Comment: @Bohemian You should put that in an answer

Comment: There is also the converse, multiple locks which must *all* be unlocked, used in a lock-out-tag-out system when multiple people are to work on a piece of equipment that absolutely must not be turned on while they are inside it.

Comment: Can someone update an answer to explain how #15 and #18 do anything?

Comment: @davidbak unlocking #15 (or #18) allows you to slide out that little bar and hence the other two bars can slide out too, unlocking the whole gate.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky - OH! That flat rectangular bar goes _through_ the round rod.  I thought I was just kind of hanging in place with the other lock locked to it.  But obviously (now!) that would be useless - _neither_ lock would be doing anything.  Thanks for making me take a good look a second time!

Comment: I thought this was a joke. I didn't expect this to teach me something so interesting. It's so simple, yet I needed to read the below answers to see it (somehow my sleep deprived brain forgot that a picture is worth a thousand words), and then I find it so wonderful. Thanks for the Q and the answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Securitywise

> It allows any of six different keys to open the gate.

One might ask

> Is there an advantage to this over having six copies of a key to one padlock.

... and the answer might be

> If the six keys also apply to other padlocks deployed separately, then the key management for operating both this gate and the other padlock is simplified.

Thus, for example,

> If the gate secures access to a locker room with six lockers, both the communal gate and the individual locker can be managed by a single key.

Comment: Exactly. ROT13(Gur xrl shapgvbaf yvxr n frphevgl cnff. Rnpu crefba unf gur xrl gung pbeerfcbaqf gb gurve yriry bs frphevgl pyrnenapr.)

Comment: Great answer with good examples.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock%6f%75%74%E2%80%93tagout, especially the picture at the top of the "Folding ... hasp", shown in use farther down the page at "A ... device applied to a hoist brake".

Comment: @SteveSummit For the sake of clarity, that link describes the opposite case, where ROT13(nyy ybpxf zhfg or bcrarq gb eryrnfr gur pynfc, engure guna nal fvatyr bar bs gurz.)

Answer (score 16):

As a technician for a telecommunications company I encountered this arrangement of locks at many tower sites, usually out in the boondocks. Each lock is assigned by the tower owner to a different company that needs access to a site. Any one lock allows the gate to be opened. The company provides keys to their technicians.  This allows the site owner to change the lock if a given company no longer needs access. Different companies might be a radio station, any of several two way radio companies, tower maintenance company, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am quite pleased that this is actually used in real life.

Comment: Most enlightening answer amongst all.

Comment: Similar is an arrangement where a chain is secured by padlocks which form links in the chain. If the padlocks are linked in series, any one key holder can gain access, but if they are fixed in parallel then all keyholders must be present.

Answer (score 9):

If you arrive to find an unlocked state, you can tell which key was used to unlock it, which may give useful info on who is inside. This might be especially useful if the space accommodates very few people - perhaps even only one person, so you could tell if the occupant(s) are cleaning staff, maintenence staff, emergency services, workers, etc

Answer (score 3):

Not seen one like this before but:

> It allows someone with a key to any single padlock to release whatever that locking pin is securing (looks like a gate but I'm not sure).
>  Depending on which padlock you have a key to, you may need to slide out up to three bars to fully release the locking pin.

Comment: Also correct answer